# Issue with docker-compose console output

Tags: node.js, docker, express, docker-compose, mocha.js

## The issue

I run `docker-compose up` when I am developping so I just have to take a quick look at the terminal (using integrated vs code terminal) to see if my unit tests, lint job and whatever are running fine.

Same if I want to `console.log` something in the API it just pop in the terminal and I can debug from it.

However, starting from this afternoon, instead of having logs from all containers, I just have logs from the containers `transpiler`, `kibana` and `apm-server`.

## What problem I want to fix

I was used to do a ctrl+s to trigger the linter and mocha container (because both of these container use nodemon so modifying files would make them output), and build the typescripts files into js (transpiler in watch mode) and have them output everything to the terminal.

No output from `api`, `mocha` nor `linter`, even though I put some `console.log` in the code...

**I did not do any major update, just switched computer (both are ubuntu linux with docker installed), and I can't figure out how to fix this issue**

## docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.3"
services:

  api:
    container_name: api
    build: .
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - elasticsearch
    command: sh -c "mkdir -p dist && touch ./dist/app.js && yarn run start"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9000/api/v1/ping"]
      interval: 1m30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3

  transpiler:
    container_name: transpiler
    build: .
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    command: yarn run transpile -w

  linter:
    container_name: linter
    build: .
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    # https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5457 --silent not working
    command: nodemon --delay 500ms --exec yarn run lint

  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo:4.0
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    command: mongod
    volumes:
      - ./db/mongodb:/data/db

  mongo_express:
    container_name: mongo_express
    restart: always
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8081"]
      interval: 2m30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./db/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - 9300:9300
      - 9200:9200
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9200"]
      interval: 1m30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3

  kibana:
    container_name: kibana
    restart: always
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.6.0
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:5601"]
      interval: 1m30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3

  logstash:
    container_name: logstash
    restart: always
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.6.0
    ports:
      - 9600:9600
    environment:
      - KILL_ON_STOP_TIMEOUT=1
    volumes:
      - ./logstash/settings/:/usr/share/logstash/config/
      - ./logstash/pipeline/:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9600"]
      interval: 1m30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3

  apm-server:
    container_name: apm_server
    restart: always
    image: docker.elastic.co/apm/apm-server:6.6.0
    ports:
      - 8200:8200
    volumes:
      - ./apm_settings/apm-server.yml:/usr/share/apm-server/apm-server.yml
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8200"]
      interval: 1m30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3

  mocha:
    container_name: mocha
    restart: always
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    command: nodemon --delay 500ms --exec yarn run test-coverage
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: 'test'

volumes:
  esdata:
```

## Dockerfile

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:10
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .gyp g++ libtool make python curl &&\
    yarn &&\
    yarn global add nodemon &&\
    apk del .gyp
```

## Data sample

When I run docker-up all output is fine:

```
mongo            | 2019-03-22T23:11:26.048+0000 I NETWORK  [conn6] end connection 172.22.0.8:52266 (3 connections now open)
apm_server       | 2019-03-22T23:11:26.048Z     INFO    [request]       beater/v2_handler.go:96 error handling request  {"request_id": "77b88109-c7c0-41a2-a28c-2343a82862bd", "method": "POST", "URL": "/intake/v2/events", "content_length": -1, "remote_address": "172.22.0.8", "user-agent": "elastic-apm-node/2.6.0 elastic-apm-http-client/7.1.1", "error": "unexpected EOF"}
api              | [nodemon] app crashed
api              | error Command failed with exit code 1.
api              | info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
mocha            | 
mocha            | 
mocha            | Express server listening on port 9000, in test mode
mocha            |   GET PING ressource
mocha            |     GET /api/v1/ ping/
mongo            | 2019-03-22T23:11:27.951+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.22.0.2:39956 #8 (4 connections now open)
mongo            | 2019-03-22T23:11:27.961+0000 I NETWORK  [conn8] received client metadata from 172.22.0.2:39956 conn8: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.1.13" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.20.7-042007-generic" }, platform: "Node.js v10.15.3, LE, mongodb-core: 3.1.11" }
mongo            | 2019-03-22T23:11:28.051+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.22.0.2:39958 #9 (5 connections now open)
mongo            | 2019-03-22T23:11:28.197+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.22.0.2:39962 #10 (6 connections now open)
mocha            |       ✓ ping api (154ms)
```

Yes I do know those logs show some errors, but my main concern is to still have them outputted in the terminal

but doing a ctrl+s just shows this : (this is my real problem) :

```
[10:59:15 PM] File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...
transpiler       | 
transpiler       | [10:59:15 PM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
transpiler       | 
apm_server       | 2019-03-22T22:59:40.309Z     INFO    [request]       beater/common_handlers.go:272   handled request {"request_id": "5948c9ee-c6fd-42ad-bd1e-acc259e1634c", "method": "POST", "URL": "/intake/v2/events", "content_length": -1, "remote_address": "172.22.0.11", "user-agent": "elastic-apm-node/2.6.0 elastic-apm-http-client/7.1.1", "response_code": 202}
kibana           | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2019-03-22T22:59:44Z","tags":[],"pid":1,"method":"get","statusCode":302,"req":{"url":"/","method":"get","headers":{"user-agent":"curl/7.29.0","host":"localhost:5601","accept":"*/*"},"remoteAddress":"127.0.0.1","userAgent":"127.0.0.1"},"res":{"statusCode":302,"responseTime":7,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET / 302 7ms - 9.0B"}
```

## What I have tried (and did not work)

- removing all containers
- removing all containers and their volume
- removing all containers and their volume and all image
- rebooting
- rebuilding (`docker-compose build`) after deleting everything
- run the `docker-compose up` cmd from a simple terminal to ensure it was not an issue with vs code integrated terminal
- restarting the docker service (`sudo systemctl restart docker`)

Comment: When you rebuilt everything most likely something changed in an npm package somewhere (prob a dependency you didn't know you had) you said you switched computers does it still work as expected on the previous computer and OS

Comment: Can't check on the other computer, it was  at work. However I doubt it comes from an npm package for two reason : first I have a yarn.lock files, and secondly I did not merge the modification I made, and tried to clone master and restart from it but same issue

Comment: When you say diff computer but both Linux... are they same version (Ubuntu? 16 18 ?Centos 6 7?

Comment: Both Ubuntu, one 16.04 and the other 18.04, but in fact you were right, I just tried again with the yarn.lock from master and now it works fine. Guess I forgot to build when I cloned from master, will try to narrow down which packet caused the issue now (now that I think about it, I did a `yarn upgrade` at work but did not rebuild, so the issue probably comes from this uprade). If you want to post an answer, i'll accept since you solved my issue :)

Comment: Awesome glad to hear you found the prob 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you rebuilt everything most likely something changed in an npm package somewhere (prob a dependency you didn't know you had).

Also, you said you switched computers does it still work as expected on the previous computer and OS?